# How to load any particular folder files from a zip dataset

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, feature-extraction

Twitter is a great source of information. Using The `Health-News-Tweets.zip` dataset contains tweets by different agencies like BBC Health, CBC Health, etc. I will  perform a clustering on these tweets and will use the elbow method to identify the ideal number of clusters.

`My Concern is how i will load only train folder files present in dataset.`

Each file contains tweets with ‘|’ as a separator.  For ex ID | Timestamp | Tweet
My further proceeding will be extracting the tweets column and perform soe preprocesing , tokenize,vectorize,clustering and so but stucked in very beginning .

Any advice Datascience community could give would be much appreciated.

[Dataset](https://github.com/ruchirm702/Datasets)

I tried this but getting error

```
import pyprind
import pandas as pd
import os


progBar = pyprind.ProgBar(3000) # initialize progress bar
df=pd.DataFrame() # empty dataframe
for s in ('test','train'):
    path="./Health-News-Tweets/train/ %s/%s" % (s) #file path
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        with open(os.path.join(path,file),'r') as infile:
            txt = infile.read()
            df= df.append([txt],ignore_index=True) #will append my content of particular text to the dataframe
            progBar.update() # updating progress bar 
            df.columns = ['ID','Timestamp','Tweet']
```

Error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2cabdcb33d40> in <module>
      7 df=pd.DataFrame() # empty dataframe
      8 for s in ('test','train'):
----> 9     path="./Health-News-Tweets/train %s/%s" % (s) #file path
     10     for file in os.listdir(path):
     11         with open(os.path.join(path,file),'r') as infile:

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

PATH : `C:\DATA SCIENCE 2021\LECTURES\FUNDAMENTAL OF LINUX & SERVER CONFIG - MODULE 1\5. MODULE 5 - Machine learning Using Python\Assignment\Health-News-Tweets`

Comment: You are trying to use two values in your string as you are using `%s` twice whereas you are only providing one actual value `s`. If you want to use the same value twice simply provide it twice using `(s, s)`.

Comment: @Oxbowerce I tried like this   `path="./Health-News-Tweets/train  %s %s" % (s,s) ` but getting error  ` FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: './Health-News-Tweets/train  test test' ` . I have provided the data if it could help .

Comment: That is a completely different error, indicating that the specified filepath does not exist. Make sure that your `path` is correct and points to an actual location on your computer.

Comment: @Oxbowerce   Alright i will try to rectify it . Thank You .

Comment: You forgot to put a forward slash between the two %s it should be like this path="./Health-News-Tweets/train  %s /%s" % (s,s)

Comment: @DataMoguls This is my path actually . `C:\DATA SCIENCE 2021\LECTURES\FUNDAMENTAL OF LINUX & SERVER CONFIG - MODULE 1\5. MODULE 5 - Machine learning Using Python\Assignment\Health-News-Tweets`  in which there 4 more folders other than train but i want to load train folder only .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried another method and successfully loaded the required files but unable to do same with above method.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

#list the files
path = r"C:\DATA SCIENCE 2021\LECTURES\FUNDAMENTAL OF LINUX & SERVER CONFIG - MODULE 1\5. MODULE 5 - Machine learning Using Python\Assignment\Health-News-Tweets\train"
filelist = os.listdir(path) 
print(filelist)

#read them into pandas
df_list=[]
for file in filelist:
    #print(file)
    df_list.append(pd.read_table(os.path.join(path,file),header=None,encoding='unicode_escape'))
```